Can skipping onStop() be used an indicator of crash?
The scenario of an Android app is like the following
MainActivity 
    - FooActivity1
    - FooActivity2

The app starts with MainActivity which can start FooActivity1 and FooActivity2.
I am trying to detect crashes in FooActivity1. Yes, I do know UncaughtExceptionHandler and use it to catch crashes but I suspect it misses many. Here is the logic that I am using:
In FooActivity1:
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      //set a flag called NormalFooActivity1Exit to false in shared preferences
      ...
    }

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
      //set the flag called NormalFooActivity1Exit to true in shareed preferences
      ...
}

In MainActivity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //Check the flag.
  //If it is true, do nothing
  //If it is false, record a crash and set the flag to true.
}

The essence is that if onStop() is skipped before the next start of the app, a crash is assumed. The reported data give me the impression that crashes are overestimated in this way.
Could anyone point out the flaw of this logic if any?

"Could anyone point out the flaw of this logic if any?" - 1) Your app could crash in the paused state and you'd miss that. 2) The system could kill your app under memory pressure and be counted as a crash. 3) The user can swipe your app away while it's active and you'd count that as a crash.

"I suspect it misses many" - based on what?

Based on Google Play Console reports. It catches only a fraction of crashes reported by Google Play Console.

"3) The user can swipe your app away while it's active and you'd count that as a crash" Does this break the Android life cycle and skip onStop()?

Yes, it instantly kills your app (try it).

I have just tried it and onStop() was called. Not sure if I did the swipe correctly. I tried it on an Android 13 device.

Interesting. It does not for me (Android 12). Open app, go to recents list, swipe app up. Don't know of the Android version or device make a difference.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can simply setup your crash detection in your app instead of activity. Because crash can happen anytime anywhere and you can't just keep setting flags for every possibility unless its a very small app.
Here is one way to get all crashes that occur in the app
class YourApp : Application(), ExceptionListener {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        setupExceptionHandler()

        //... other code
    }

    override fun uncaughtException(thread: Thread, throwable: Throwable) {
        // TODO: Here Make sure you are logging this issue some where like Crashlytics or in whatever counter you have in preferences.
        // Also indicate that something went wrong to the user like maybe a dialog or an activity.
      
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "An Uncaught Exception occured : ${throwable.message}",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        log(throwable)
    }

    private fun setupExceptionHandler() {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Looper.loop()
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    uncaughtException(Looper.getMainLooper().thread, e)
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { t, e ->
            uncaughtException(t, e)
        }
    }


}

interface ExceptionListener {
    fun uncaughtException(thread: Thread, throwable: Throwable)
}

This is a more generalized approach, also it may not be suitable to apps in which crashing is required to close the app because this code will stop the app from closing upon crash. So use it wisely.

Thank you for trying to lend a hand. This is about a specific activity, not for catching all crashes of an app. I have just edited my question by making the following statement boldface. "Yes, I do know UncaughtExceptionHandler and use it to catch crashes but I suspect it misses many" I should have emphasized this statement more to avoid confusion.
